# No option to send direct messages in chatter

Tags: experience-cloud

I don't understand these directions:
In Experience Builder, click the Profile Header component on the Home page and select Include My Messages.

Can someone send a screenshot? I don't see Profile Header on the Home page. Currently, no one has the ability to see or send messages. This is the documentation:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_enable_direct_messages.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are likely old. The profile menu got an [overhaul](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_customizable_user_profile_menu.htm&type=5&release=226) in Summer 20 release for most templates. Now you can add options to profile menu just like navigation bar. To set the options, click the menu, highlighted as `1` and then click `2` and then setup the menu items.

[image: Profile menu]

[image: User menu items]